# For $n>>i$ the maps $h^i(X) \to h^i(X^n)$ and $k^i(X) \to k^i(X^n)$ induced by the inclusion $X^n \to X$ are isomorphisms.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cw-complexes

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. For a fixed CW complex $Y$, consider the functors 
$$ h^n(X)=\oplus _{i=0} ^n (H^i(X;R) \otimes_R H^{n-i} (Y;R) ) ,$$
$$k^n(X)=H^n (X \times Y;R).$$

(Here $X$ is a CW complex.)

In the proof of Proposition 3.17 in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology, Hatcher says that when $n$ is sufficiently large with respect to $i$, then the maps $h^i(X) \to h^i(X^n)$ and $k^i(X) \to k^i(X^n)$ induced by the inclusion $X^n \to X$ are isomorphisms.

I cannot see why does this result holds. But I think that the similar results from homology may imply this result, via the universal coefficient theorem for cohomology. I know that the inclusion $X^n \to X$ induces an isomorphism on homology $H_k(X^n) \to H_k(X)$ is $k<n$. Can I prove the result using this? Or is there another way to prove the result?

Comment: The more relevant result is the one for cohomology, but this does follow from the result you state for homology. The statement for $h_n$ follows directly from this result, and the statement for $k_n$ follows from this result plus a tiny bit of analysis of how $X^n \times Y$ fits into $X \times Y $.

Comment: What is $h^i$ is it just a typo and do you mean $h_i$?

Comment: @NoelLundström Oh yes sorry I edited it.

Comment: Using simplicial cohomology we can prove that $H^j(X) \rightarrow H^{j}(X^n)$ for $n>>i$ and all $j<i$ is an isomorphism. It follows that $h^i(X) \rightarrow h^i(X^n)$ is an isomorphism aswell since all of the maps $H^{j}(X) \otimes_R H^{i-j}(Y) \rightarrow H^{j}(X^n) \otimes_R H^{i-j}(Y)$ defined on summands are isomorphisms.